# Travis CI deploy with cron.yaml to gcp

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci

I am trying to setup cron jobs for a website hosted on GCP. We use Travis CI to build our site and deploy it to GAE. I have created a cron.yaml to run some tests, but I don't know how to deploy it to our site.

Here is my cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: TestPush Notification
  url: /test
  schedule: every 1 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
  timezone: America/Vancouver
```

Here is my .travis.yaml:

```
sudo: false
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_xxxx_key -iv $encrypted_xxxx_iv -in client-secret.json.enc -out client-secret.json -d
- export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/lib"
install:
- pip install -r requirements-prd.txt -t lib/
- pip install requests --upgrade -t lib/
- cd ubyssey/static
- npm install -g gulp
- npm install
script:
- gulp build
after_success:
# clean up node_modules
- rm -rf node_modules
- cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}
# use deploy settings
- mv _settings/settings-dpl.py ubyssey/settings.py
- python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
# gzip static files
- find ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gcs -type f -exec gzip "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \;
# replace deploy settings with production settings
- rm ubyssey/settings.py ubyssey/settings.pyc
- mv _settings/settings-prd.py ubyssey/settings.py
- rm -rf .git/
deploy:
  - provider: gcs
    access_key_id: <omitted>
    secret_access_key:
      secure: <omitted>
    bucket: ubyssey
    skip_cleanup: true
    acl: public-read
    local-dir: ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gcs
    detect_encoding: true
    cache_control: "max-age=31536000"
    on:
      tags: true
  - provider: gae
    keyfile: client-secret.json
    project: ubyssey-prd
    default: true
    version: ubyssey-${TRAVIS_TAG//./-} # Replace periods with hyphens
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      tags: true
```

How can I get the travis build to deploy the app with the cron.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like travis uses `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/google-app-engine/#Other-Available-Configuration-Options

So you need travis to explicity add cron.yaml like this `gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

[It's hard to tell if travis's config lets you specify multiple deployables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/google-app-engine/#Other-Available-Configuration-Options)

You may have to add a duplicate `provider: gae` entry with `config` pointed to your `cron.yaml`

Comment: It appears to deploy the cron job! Thanks